# ERROR: SWT folder '' does not exist. Please set ANDROID_SWT .. a get this error after a SDK update

Tags: android, mobile, sdk

My `SDK Manager` does not work after an `android sdk manager` update to the last version, the sdk manager.exe run correctly before the update. Now i get this message when i run the `android.bat` on the command line:

```
ERROR: SWT folder '' does not exist. Please set ANDROID_SWT to point to the folder containing swt.jar for your platform.
```

can u give me a solution or some instruction to change into my android.bat

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I added this line :

```
set java_exe=C:\Windows\System32\java.exe
```

after this lines in my android.bat :

```
rem Check we have a valid Java.exe in the path.
set java_exe=
call lib\find_java.bat
if not defined java_exe goto :EOF
```

the SDK Manager.exe run correctly now :D !

Comment: Thanks, it works fine now.Sometimes android sdk update tool really sucks.

Comment: I had to add ```set java_exe=%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe``` instead.

Comment: Where you have added this line - "set java_exe=C:\Windows\System32\java.exe"

Answer (score 10):

delete

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('"%java_exe%" -jar lib\archquery.jar') do set swt_path=lib\%%a
```

add, if you using x86_64 system

```
set swt_path=lib\x86_64
```

otherwise

```
set swt_path=lib\x86
```

Answer (score 3):

Add this line -:

```
set java_exe=%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe
```

after these lines in your android.bat :

```
set java_exe=
call lib\find_java.bat
if not defined java_exe goto :EOF
```

and this line -:

```
set swt_path=lib\x86_64
```

after these lines :

```
rem Set SWT.Jar path based on current architecture (x86 or x86_64)
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('"%java_exe%" -jar lib\archquery.jar') do set swt_path=lib\%%a
```

In case your system is 32-bit, change

```
set swt_path=lib\x86_64
```

to

```
set swt_path=lib\x86
```

Answer (score 2):

Go to windows environment variables setting, create a new(if it already exists, edit the old one) variable with name: `JAVA_HOME` and value to your installed JDK path like:
`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\` and also add this to end of your path variable: `%JAVA_HOME%/bin`

Answer (score 1):

Actually Google did a mistake here, please open find_java.bat in the folder "\sdk\tools\lib", in #27 line, there show:

```
find /i "x86" > NUL && set arch_ext=32 || set arch_ext=64
```

delete the blank between "arch_ext=32" and "||", like "arch_ext=32||", reopen the cmd, and all tools will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

i just fixed this by adding

```
echo GHETTO NOGGAR RAGGED OVERRIDE ANDROID_SWT
set ANDROID_SWT=C:\NVPACK\android-sdk-windows\tools\lib\x86_64
echo %ANDROID_SWT%
```

right before

```
rem The global ANDROID_SWT always override the SWT.Jar path
if defined ANDROID_SWT set swt_path=%ANDROID_SWT%
if exist "%swt_path%" goto SetPath
    echo ERROR: SWT folder '%swt_path%' does not exist.
    echo Please set ANDROID_SWT to point to the folder containing swt.jar for your platform.
    goto :EOF
```

in my android.bat (CodeWorks 1r5 installs it to C:\NVPACK\android-sdk-windows\tools )

Answer (score 0):

I've ran into this issue before as well. After some tinkering with android.bat, I found something was weird with the relative path to archquery jar. So I ended up changing:

**for /f "delims=" %%a in ('"%java_exe%" -jar lib\archquery.jar') do set 
swt_path=lib\%%a**

to

**for /f "delims=" %%a in ('"%java_exe%" -jar %~dp0\lib\archquery.jar') do set 
swt_path=lib\%%a**

(%~dp0 being window's magical current script directory variable)

Unfortunately when you update your sdk tools, this change will be wiped so you have to make it every time. Wish I knew why this change is necessary( maybe someone else knows more) but this fix works for me for how often I need to open the SDK manager vs updating

**I solved with this, other solutions doesn't work for me**

Answer (score 0):

If u get `"xcopy' is not recognized as an internal or external command"`

This Worked for me. Add `C:\Windows\System32` to Windows Environment Variables called PATH.

Steps:

- Windows+Pause Break
- Advanced settings
- Click on variable named PATH
- If not exists add `C:\Windows\System32`. Don't forget to add the
  separator `;` before your added content

Open `android.bat`

Answer (score 0):

I have same error message.
I just recover android-sdk/tools then everything work fine as always.

Answer (score 0):

> i know its late but it will help others,

Its confusing so im sharing my file

You Need to change

1. **set java_exe=** to your **installed java location**

In My Case: **set java_exe=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_271\bin\java.exe**

2. **<Your_User_Name>** to *Your User Name*
   In my case: **C:\Users\SomeOne\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\lib\monkeyrunner-26.0.0-dev.jar
3. If U have a 64-bit system then change **set swt_path** to:

**set swt_path=C:\Users<Your_User_Name>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\lib\x86_64\swt.jar**

In Case of 32-bit change to:
**set swt_path=C:\Users<Your_User_Name>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\lib\x86\swt.jar**

> Here my working file

```
@echo off
rem Copyright (C) 2010 The Android Open Source Project
rem
rem Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
rem you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
rem You may obtain a copy of the License at
rem
rem      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
rem
rem Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
rem distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
rem WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
rem See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
rem limitations under the License.

rem don't modify the caller's environment
setlocal

rem Set up prog to be the path of this script, including following symlinks,
rem and set up progdir to be the fully-qualified pathname of its directory.
set prog=%~f0

rem Change current directory and drive to where the script is, to avoid
rem issues with directories containing whitespaces.
cd /d %~dp0

rem Check we have a valid Java.exe in the path.
set java_exe=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_271\bin\java.exe
call ..\lib\find_java.bat
if not defined java_exe goto :EOF

for /f %%a in ("C:\Users\<Your_User_Name>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\lib\monkeyrunner-26.0.0-dev.jar") do set jarfile=%%~nxa
set frameworkdir=.
set libdir=

if exist %frameworkdir%\%jarfile% goto JarFileOk
    set frameworkdir=lib

if exist %frameworkdir%\%jarfile% goto JarFileOk
    set frameworkdir=..\framework

:JarFileOk

set jarpath=%frameworkdir%\%jarfile%

if not defined ANDROID_SWT goto QueryArch
    set swt_path=C:\Users\<Your_User_Name>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\lib\x86_64\swt.jar
    goto SwtDone

:QueryArch

    for /f "delims=" %%a in ('%frameworkdir%\..\bin\archquery') do set swt_path=C:\Users\<Your_User_Name>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\lib\x86_64\swt.jar


:SwtDone

if exist "%swt_path%" goto SetPath
    echo SWT folder '%swt_path%' does not exist.
    echo Please set ANDROID_SWT to point to the folder containing swt.jar for your platform.
    exit /B

:SetPath

call "%java_exe%" -Xmx512m "-Djava.ext.dirs=%frameworkdir%;%swt_path%" -Dcom.android.monkeyrunner.bindir=..\framework -jar %jarpath% %*
```